# Animating frame occasionally works

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, animatewithduration

Here's my function that animates my view

```
func animateViewMoving (up:Bool, moveValue :CGFloat) {

    let movementDuration:NSTimeInterval = 0.3
    let movement:CGFloat = ( up ? -moveValue : moveValue)
    self.view.setNeedsLayout()
    UIView.animateWithDuration(movementDuration, animations: {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.view.frame.origin.y += movement
    })

}
```

I call this function on these two functions of `UITextFieldDelegate`

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {

        animateViewMoving(true, moveValue: 200)

}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {

        animateViewMoving(false, moveValue: 200)

}
```

The problem is this- Whenever I run my build and open the view for the first time, the view shifts up on pressing the textField and shifts down when editing the textField ends. However if I go back to a previous view and enter the view again, the view does not shift up on pressing the textField. Why is `animateWithDuration`  working irregularly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I don't know swift so I'll just write my solution in objective-C.

I assume that you are using AutoLayout. If that's the case I suggest that when you animate a view, you animate it's constraints, not the frame of the view. I encountered a lot of problems before when I animate the frame of the view.

Here's a sample:

```
- (void)moveSubview
{
    _subviewLeadingSuperLeading.constant = 20; //just a sample to move the subview horizontally.

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^
     {
         [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
     }

     completion:^(BOOL isFinished)
     {
         //Do whatever you want
     }];
}
```

I hope this will help you. :)

Comment: It did help. Can you tell me why this was necessary?

Comment: That's because you are using autolayout. In autolayout, it's the constrants that dictates the positioning of your subviews. The frame is just the result of the autolayout process, so it shouldn't be changed. :)

Comment: Thanks for the help!:)